# LaTeX formula in Shiny panel

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I want to display a -LaTeX formated- formula in a Shiny panel, but I can't find a way to combine `textOutput` with `withMathJax`. I tried the following but it didn't work. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

--ui.r

```
...
    tabPanel("Diagnostics", h4(textOutput("diagTitle")),
withMathJax(textOutput("formula")),
),
...
```

--server.r

```
...
output$formula <- renderText({
    print(paste0("Use this formula: $$\\hat{A}_{\\small{\\textrm{M€}}} =", my_calculated_value,"$$"))
})
...
```

Comment: strange, it run fines as is on my machine (I just removed the `print` but shouldn't change much). I have shiny_0.11.1 though. Is this script file: `<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"...` loaded on your page? Looks like there was a fix for that link so maybe that's the issue

Comment: Yes, In page source I saw it's loaded. src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html
http://sas-and-r.blogspot.gr/2015/12/write-in-line-equations-in-your-shiny.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+SASandR+(SAS+and+R)

Answer (score 10):

Use `uiOutput` on the UI side and `renderUI` on the server side for dynamic content.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  withMathJax(),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Diagnostics", 
    h4(textOutput("diagTitle")),
    uiOutput("formula")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$formula <- renderUI({
    my_calculated_value <- 5
    withMathJax(paste0("Use this formula: $$\\hat{A}_{\\small{\\textrm{M€}}} =", my_calculated_value,"$$"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

More examples: http://shiny.leg.ufpr.br/daniel/019-mathjax/

Comment: Internet environment is required for TeX.

Comment: To anyone out there trying this, please note that you need to enclose your formula with `$$`, otherwise it will just show up as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

ui.R

```
tabPanel("Diagnostics", h4(textOutput("diagTitle")),
    withMathJax(uiOutput("formula")),
)
```

server.R

```
output$formula <- renderUI({
    return(HTML(paste0("<p>", "Use this formula: $$\\hat{A}_{\\small{\\textrm{M€}}} =", my_calculated_value,"$$","</p>")))
})
```

Comment: The output is still like that: Use this formula: $$\hat{A}_{\small{\textrm{M€}}} =1.69$$

Answer (score 0):

How about using `renderPrint()`?

Minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

 output$formula <- renderPrint({
     print(paste0("Use this formula: $$\\hat{A}_{\\small{\\textrm{M€}}} =", 1,"$$"))
})

}

ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    ),

    mainPanel(
      withMathJax(textOutput("formula"))
    )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT:**
To me it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me (R version 3.1.1, Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit), shiny_0.10.2.2)

Comment: \hat{A} should look like this: Â