# Detect Internet Environment in R

Tags: r

How to make , e.g., a logical R object `xxx` indicating internet environment. If `xxx=TRUE` then online and if `xxx=FALSE` then off line.

---

motivation

I use [TeX scripts in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169101/latex-formula-in-shiny-panel) in which internet environment is required.

If off line, then any tex script remains its raw appearance.

Comment: There isn’t really a reliable way to test if a machine is “online”, and it would be relatively useless anyway: You don’t actually care whether the user is online; instead, you care whether the user can access your specific online resource. So try to access it, and handle failure gracefully with a timeout.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I understand your suggestion. But,... I do not know where  such web page exist for tex. And how to count the time to access the web page via R. It is difficult for me :-D

Comment: Such as site *does not exist* for TeX. I’m not sure which web resource you’re trying to access in fact. MatJaX is a JavaScript library that’s present locally once loaded, so you wouldn’t need to test internet connectivity anyway.

Comment: This might be useful to you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076593/how-to-determine-if-you-have-an-internet-connection-in-r

Comment: Thank you for three pearons, I read your comments. Thank you.